# Geopandas Mollweide projection

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas

I´ve a .gpkg file in Mollweide projection. When I open it in geopandas, it shows me  the correct crs information:

```
df1.crs
>>>>> {'init': 'epsg:54009'}
```

I´d like to re-project it to EPSG 4326, in a way to cross this layer with a global map in lat/long. If I try:

```py
df1.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```

I get the error message:

> pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: +init=epsg:54009 +type=crs

How can I proceed to reproject those layers in a way I could intersect them?

Comment: What version of pyproj are you using?

Comment: joris, the last one, I just updated it. I think it´s because EPSG 54009 is not directly supported.

Comment: Mollweide CRS projection string is `esri:54009`, not `epsg:54009`, [see](https://epsg.io/54009). Try setting this string with the `set_crs()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The Mollweide CRS projection is not "EPSG:54009" but "ESRI:54009". You should try:

```py
df1.to_crs("ESRI:54009")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the OGC Well Known Text definition:

```
PROJCS["Sphere_Mollweide",
    GEOGCS["Unknown datum based upon the Authalic Sphere",
        DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_Authalic_Sphere",
            SPHEROID["Sphere",6371000,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6035"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["ESRI","53009"]]
```

Source: https://epsg.io/53009

In .NET, i can then get the projection from the esri-string:

```
            // Mollweide equal-area projection 
            // DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo toMollweide = DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(53009); // not working 

            // https://epsg.io/53009
            DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo toMollweide = DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromEsriString(@"
PROJCS[""Sphere_Mollweide"",
    GEOGCS[""Unknown datum based upon the Authalic Sphere"",
        DATUM[""Not_specified_based_on_Authalic_Sphere"",
            SPHEROID[""Sphere"", 6371000, 0],
            AUTHORITY[""EPSG"", ""6035""]],
        PRIMEM[""Greenwich"", 0],
        UNIT[""Degree"", 0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION[""Mollweide""],
    PARAMETER[""central_meridian"", 0],
    PARAMETER[""false_easting"", 0],
    PARAMETER[""false_northing"", 0],
    UNIT[""metre"", 1,
        AUTHORITY[""EPSG"", ""9001""]],
    AXIS[""Easting"", EAST],
    AXIS[""Northing"", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY[""ESRI"", ""53009""]]
");
```